# Restoring/Verifying In-App Purchases in Windows 10

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-10

Can anyone point me to a resource, or explain to me how to check the purchases a user has already made in a Windows UWP app. My app does not have any information by which I can identify the individual user. I looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything on retrieving receipts of already purchased items.

I could inform my server of any successful purchase and identify the user's device. But then the same user won't have access to his/her IAPs on another devices. What I need is a method that retrieves all the receipts of the user currently logged into the Windows Store.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in the documentation after all (for the Simulator):

```
LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;

// get the license info for one of the app's in-app offers
ProductLicense inAppOfferLicense = 
    licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["MyFavoriteInAppOffer"];

// get the expiration date of this in-app offer
DateTimeOffset expirationDate = inAppOfferLicense.ExpirationDate;
```